# Joomla adds closing tags in HTML

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

i'm trying to copy some html to joomla. yesterday it worked fine, but today i saw that something was wrong, i looked in google Chrome and saw that the line of code that should be like this:

```
     <div class="caption" id="five">
       <a href="#"><h5>Windows 10 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet</p></h5></a>
        </div>
```

Was now:

```
     <div class="caption" id="five">
       <a href="#"><h5>Windows 10 </h><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet</p></a>
        </div>
```

I tried to change filtering etc, but i can not fix it. Also it was very strange to me that it worked perfectly yesterday but today it did not. Can someone help?

(i'm using JCE editor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though they are both block elements, you should not be using `<p>` tags inside `<h*`> tags as it's not semantically correct. Thing like this may cause editors such as your JCE to throw a hissy fit.

Also, `<a>` is an inline elements, therefore inless you specify it as a block element, your `<h5>` tag should be the parent, not the child

Instead, what you should be doing is:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="caption" id="five">
    <h5><a href="#">Windows 10 <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sitamet</span></a></h5>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.caption > a {
    display: block;
}
```